# Combine string and cell reference and convert to formula

Tags: excel

I'm trying to connect to a scada system via DDE function.

First column contains tags of the points that I want to get their values and second column contains the formula.

The formulas I use is as follows: =Datahub|Datasim!AAA_PV1 , Datahub|Datasim!AAA_PV2, ...etc.

Where AAA_PV1, AAA_PV2 are the variables that will be changed located at A1, A2 cells.

So how could I concatinate the constant part of the formula (=Datahub|Datasim!) with the variable part (AAA_PV1) (AAA_PV2) ...etc

Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can put `'Datahub|Datasim'!` in a cell, for example D1, and then use the `Indirect()` function.

So assuming the values are to be put in B1, B2 etc. (corresponding to the values of A1, A2 etc.) Put this formula in B1:

```
=Indirect($D$1&A1)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately this didn't work.. I think some apostrophes have to be added.

Comment: Yes you are correct. The formula in your original post won't work either, since apostrophes are missing there as well. I edited my answer.